# How to apply changes to an installed multi-file add-on without restarting .blend-file?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I was revisiting and enhancing some of the add-ons I've created in the past. I wonder, is there a way to update an installed multi-file add-on (if it has been changed) without reloading the Blender file itself? I've tried a lot of approaches, but all of them failed miserably. Here's a list of the things I've already tried (none of them worked):

1. Reload Scripts — `bpy.ops.script.reload()`
2. Using `unregister` and then `register` modules in the `sys.modules`

At this stage, I thought that options (1) and (2) could have failed because only the `\_\_init\_\_` file was being reloaded. So I've come up with the following option:

3. I decided to `unregister` and then `register` every `.py` file in the add-on folder (if it contains register/unregister functions). This process begins by reloading `\_\_init\_\_`, followed by reloading every `.py` file that could be unregistered or registered.

This was quite an advanced solution, which did perfectly what I intended it to do (unregister/register every module), though it was not enough for Blender. Is there any way to reload modified (multi-file) add-on without restarting the Blender file?

I experienced this problem with two versions of Blender: the latest one (4.1.0) and the previous one (4.0.2). I've made a very simple multi-file add-on specially for testing things. You could use it to test your theories. It displays a message at the bottom of the screen. If you think you have a working solution – please, test it by changing the message from "MY MSG 1" to "MY MSG 2".

[image]

The message text could be edited in the third line of `test_msg.py`

[image]

[Download Test Add-on](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-51Trq5SVG5jgRCBrOG7Ozw97xky0Tm-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `register()` and `unregister()` you make Blender refresh what he is supposed to work with. The modules themselves are cached by Python and aren't reloaded from the disk.

The underlying evaluation of the module's code triggered with `from . import test_msg` is executed only once. That includes the assignment `MESSAGE = 'MY MSG 1'`. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache

You need an operator that unregisters your addon, **reloads the addon's Python modules** and registers the addon again.

`__init__.py`

```py
bl_info = {
    "name": "test_msg",
    "author": "Yaroslav A.",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "[Add] > [Test MSG]",
    "description": "A simple add-on to test things",
    "category": "Generic",
}

from . import test_msg

import bpy

class TESTMSG_OT_reload_addon(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'wm.msg_test_reload_addon'
    bl_label = 'Reload Test MSG'

    def execute(self, context):

        import importlib
        import sys

        test_msg.unregister()

        for module in list(sys.modules):
            if module.startswith(__package__ + '.'):
                importlib.reload(sys.modules[module])

        test_msg.register()
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TESTMSG_OT_reload_addon)
    test_msg.register()

                    
def unregister():
    test_msg.unregister()
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TESTMSG_OT_reload_addon)
```

To be able to find the reload operator in the global search menu without it being exposed to the UI, Developers Extras must be enabled: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/interface.html#bpy-types-preferencesview-show-developer-ui

You also want to read about `importlib.reload` side effects:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58947002/11799308

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Huge-HUGE thanks for explanations, code and for the useful links.